# Filter step-up ring sets - any with single target size?

Tags: filters, adapter

I have lenses of several different filter diameters and I've been looking at the various step-up ring sets that are available so that I can use a single ND1000 neutral density filter that I plan to purchase, in the 77mm size (the largest diameter lens I have). It seems that all of the step-up ring sets available have varying "to" as well as "from" sizes, e.g. one particular set includes the following converter rings:

- 49mm-52mm
- 52mm-55mm
- 55mm-58mm
- 58mm-62mm
- 62mm-67mm
- 67mm-72mm
- 72mm-77mm

What I'd like however is a set with something like the following:

- 49mm-77mm
- 52mm-77mm
- 55mm-77mm 
  ...and so on.

Why is it that sets such as this don't seem to be available? Is it expected that the user would stack all of the necessary rings in order to arrive at the required conversion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's *possible* that a retailer would package "X-to-77mm" step-up ring sets, but I've never seen such a set. However, for most photographers, it's not a hassle to get a dedicated "X-to-77mm" (or replace 77mm with whatever your largest lens filter diameter is) step-up ring for each lens.

Those rings are individually readily available from Amazon, B&H Photo Video, Adorama, and other internet retailers.

I have a few lenses with 77mm filter threads, a couple with 67mm, and individual lenses with 52mm, 55mm, and 62mm. What I did was step up each of my (52, 55, 62) lenses to 67mm, and bought 67mm lens caps for each, and left the step-up rings on those lenses permanently. Then, I have a small handful of 67mm-to-77mm rings that I keep with my filters. That way, I have a good chance of reusing lens caps amongst lenses, while still keeping the outer diameter profile of the smaller lenses somewhat reasonable, rather than having ridiculously large step-up rings and filters attached to my lenses all the time. This is convenient for carrying, changing lenses, and attaching/removing filters.

Bonus points: Try to get brass step-up rings, rather than aluminum. Aluminum rings are cheaper, but can have the tendency to stick, making them hard to remove. Brass does not have that characteristic. See also: [How can I keep lens filters and other attachments from sticking on the lens?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/63460/11924)

Comment: Thanks - I was hoping to save costs by buying a set rather than individual ones, that's all. It just doesn't seem logical to me, the way that they are sold. Thanks for your advice regarding the brass rings!